# This and parentElement

Tags: javascript

I want to manipulate an element if a child of it gets clicked (by adding a css-class to it).

I try do it like this:

```
function mahlzeitRaus() {
    console.log("Raus");
    //this.className += " not";
    this.parentElement.className += " not";

}
```

And that

```
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('trigger_mahlzeit_delete')[0].addEventListener('click', mahlzeitRaus);
    }
```

I do have 2 questions here which I know is against the etiquette but they are they bound to each other I guess:

1 By using *('trigger_mahlzeit_delete')[0]* I always just target the first element that has that class but I want to target each one that gets clicked. How would I do that instead?

2 Obviously the targeting of the parent-element doesn't work but at least something is logged to the console so I guess the way I target the parent-element isn't correct (and I suppose it will be the same issue as the first question) but how could I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: I need to prevent getElementById btw...

Answer (score 1):

Pass `this` to the function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('trigger_mahlzeit_delete')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){mahlzeitRaus(this)});
```

Then use that inside the function:

```
function mahlzeitRaus(el) {
  console.log("Raus");
  //this.className += " not";
  el.parentElement.className += " not";
}
```